# How to generate xml with a node that specifies namespace for itself?

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

This is the result I'd like to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
</types>
```

but using the straightforward solution:

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$schema = $document->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'xs:schema');

$types = $document->createElement('types');
$types->appendChild($schema);

$document->appendChild($types);

echo $document->saveXML();
```

I only get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<types xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
</types>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in order of appending children. Try this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$types = $document->createElement('types');
$schema = $document->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'xs:schema');

$document->appendChild($types);
$types->appendChild($schema);

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Comment: How did you know that? Is there some logic behind that or any reasonable explanation? The terrible thing is that this is a simplification and I have to add them in the order like in the question :-(

Comment: @zerkms I need to re-read the docs to give you the precise answer for the question in your comment